# Files not getting transferred from Apache web server to Tomcat application server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Apache 2.4 is the web server. Apache Tomcat 9.0.0M15 is the application server. We have deployed the entire war on the tomcat. We have used web server only for redirection and load balancing. We use java 1.7 + spring 3.2.5 + hibernate 4

Application allowed user to upload files. When we directly use the application url, we are able to upload files.

However, when we upload files using the web server url, the files do not get uploaded. File object is not populated when we see the logs.

Could you please help? Is there any configuration changes on web server or app server so that the files reach the application server?

Comment: with mod_proxy_ajp?

Comment: how are you uploading the files? with a <form> and <input type="file">?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, apache is the web server and tomcat is the application one, meaning apache doesn't know anything about your java app, if you want to use your application possibilities, you should redirect call to tomcat, so the application(meaning its servlets) will do the job